# Killing all processes started by a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have a number of bash scripts which are carrying out a lot of similar tasks, and they use some external binary programs. The problem is that the binary programs are often not exiting terminating as they should. Since my scripts run them thousands of times, it happens quickly that a lot of idle/nearly dead instances of these processes are accumulating. I cannot fix these programs, therefore I need to make sure my bash scripts are terminating them.

There are some topics here in SE already which deal with this task of terminating processes of bash scripts. I have applied and tested what was written there, and to some extend it works. But it does not work well enough for my case, and I don't understand why, therefore I am opening a new question.

My scripts have a hierarchy, here shown in a simplified manner:
Script A calls script B, and script B calls multiple instances of script C in parallel to use all the CPUs. E.g. script B runs 5 instances of script C in parallel, and when one instance of script C is completed it starts a new one, altogether thousands of runs of script C. And script C calls several external binaries/commands which don't terminate nicely. They are in parallel in the background and communicate with each other.

However, my script C is able to detect when the external commands are done with their work, even if they have not terminated, and then my bash script exits.

In order to terminate all the external programs during completion of the bash script, I have added an exit trap:

```
# Exit cleanup
cleanup_exit() {
    # Running the termination in an own process group to prevent it from preliminary termination. Since it will run in the background it will not cause any delays
    setsid nohup bash -c "
        touch /tmp/trace_1  # To see if this code was really executed to this point

        # Trapping signals to prevent that this function is terminated preliminary
        trap '' SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGTERM SIGHUP ERR
        touch /tmp/trace_2  # To see if this code was really executed to this point

        # Terminating the main processes
        kill ${pids[@]} 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        touch /tmp/trace_3
        sleep 5
        touch /tmp/trace_4
        kill -9 ${pids[@]} 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        touch /tmp/trace_5

        # Terminating the child processes of the main processes
        echo "Terminating the child processes"
        pkill -P ${pids[@]} 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        touch /tmp/trace_6
        sleep 1
        pkill -9 -P ${pids[@]} 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        touch /tmp/trace_7

        # Terminating everything else which is still running and which was started by this script
        pkill -P $$ || true
        touch /tmp/trace_8
        sleep 1
        pkill -9 -P $$ || true
        touch /tmp/trace_9
    "
}
trap "cleanup_exit" SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGTERM EXIT
```

Now this seems to work if I run only very few instances of script C in parallel. If I increase the number to more, e.g. 10 (the workstation is powerful and should be able to handle dozens of parallel instances of script C and the external programs in parallel), then it does not work anymore, and hundreds of instances of the external programs are accumulating quickly.

But I don't understand why. For instance the PID of one of those processes which accumulated was 32048. And in the logs I can see the execution of the exit trap:

```
+ echo ' * Snapshot 190 completed after 3 seconds.'
 * Snapshot 190 completed after 3 seconds.
+ break
+ cleanup_exit
+ echo

+ echo ' * Cleaning up...'
 * Cleaning up...
+ setsid nohup bash -c '
        touch /tmp/trace_1  # To see if this code was really executed to this point

        # Trapping signals to prevent that this function is terminated preliminary
        trap '\'''\'' SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGTERM SIGHUP ERR
        touch /tmp/trace_2  # To see if this code was really executed to this point

        # Terminating the main processes
        kill 31678' '32048 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        touch /tmp/trace_3
        sleep 5
        touch /tmp/trace_4
        kill -9 31678' '32048 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        touch /tmp/trace_5

        # Terminating the child processes of the main processes
        pkill -P 31678' '32048 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        touch /tmp/trace_6
        sleep 1
        pkill -9 -P 31678' '32048 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        touch /tmp/trace_7

        # Terminating everything else which is still running and which was started by this script
        pkill -P 31623 || true
        touch /tmp/trace_8
        sleep 1
        pkill -9 -P 31623 || true
        touch /tmp/trace_9
    '
```

Clearly, the PID of this process was used in the exit trap, but the process did not quit. For testing I run the kill command manually again on this process, and then it quit indeed.

And most interestingly, only the trace files up to number 5 appear. Nothing beyond 5, but why?

**Update**: I just found out that even if I run just one instance of script C in parallel, i.e. sequential, it works well only for some time. Suddenly at some time point processes are not getting terminated anymore, but are starting to hang around forever and accumulating. The machine should not be overloaded with one process in parallel. And in my log files the exit trap is still called properly as before, no difference there. Memory is free as well, CPUs are also partially free.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and try to create Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: @Vinny: This is generally a good idea, but would be very hard in this case because the external programs which are used by my scripts which cause the problem are large and complex scientific packages (not available in any repos), and I don't have other more simple programs which would reproduce their behavior.

Comment: well, think that someone who wants to try and help needs about ~10min just to read the question. Just sayin', your question would be much more responsive if it was shorter (or more pin-pointed to what is the issue)

Comment: @Vinny: I understand your point. I tried to include only the relevant information, but the context is also important for the solution, because it rules out certain solutions. And if I would reduce my question further and leave out some of the context information, it might also coincide with other questions already asked. Therefore I would like to keep some of the specificity of the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good sanity check for any shell script is to run ShellCheck on it:

```
Line 9:
        kill ${pids[@]} 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || true
             ^-- SC2145: Argument mixes string and array. Use * or separate argument.
```

And indeed, your xtrace does something strange on this line:

```
kill 31678' '32048 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || true
          ^^^--- What is this?
```

The problem here is that your `${pids[@]}` expands into multiple words, and `bash -c` only interprets the first word. Here's a simplified example:

```
pids=(2 3 4)
bash -c "echo killing ${pids[@]}"
```

This ends up writing `killing 2` with no mention of 3 or 4. It's equivalent to running

```
bash -c "echo killing 2" "3" "4"
```

where the other pids just become the positional parameters `$0` and `$1` instead of being part of the executed command.

Instead, like [ShellCheck suggested](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2145), you wanted `*` to concatenate all the pids with spaces and insert them as a single argument:

```
pids=(2 3 4)
bash -c "echo killing ${pids[*]}"
```

which prints `killing 2 3 4`.

Comment: You are ingenious, thanks so much for your help! Will test it right now... :-)

Comment: First tests seem to work indeed, no processes have accumulated so far. However, for a final conclusion I need to run longer tests. In the mean time I found something else. I have added trace-files in each step of the exit trap (see updated post above). Before I added the correction you had suggested, only the very first trace file appeared. Now with your correction, the trace files up to number 5 appear. But not more. Any idea why? The script B calls kill -9 on script C after 8 seconds, but the termination code should not be affected since it is run with setsid to my understanding.

Comment: Actually  pkill -P $$ might kill the exit-code, even with setsid, since its ppid is the pid of script C since it has started it. But that would mean that at least trace file 7 should be reached.

Comment: I found in the solution. There was an echo command in my original code which used double quotes after trace-file 5, and bash seemed to have interpreted this as the end of the exit-code... Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: much better than pulling the whole thing apart and starting over again! ... I've removed my comments and upvoted this answer. Good luck to all!

Comment: @shellter: Still thanks a lot for your suggestions, really appreciated it! (I now have removed my comments which were in response to your comments)